# iOS Facebook Open Graph API how to set a "reference" property type

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

I am trying to post an action

```
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
    [params setObject:[self getHomePageTitle] forKey:@"article"];
    [params setObject:[self getHomePageTitle] forKey:@"title"];
    [params setObject:@"xxxxxxxxxxx" forKey:@"app_id"];        
    [params setObject:self.regularUrlForFacebookSharing forKey:@"url"];
    [params setValue:appDelegate.facebook.accessToken forKey:@"access_token"];

    [appDelegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/news.reads" 
                         andParams:params
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                       andDelegate:appDelegate.facebook];
```

And everything I set for "article" I keep getting the error following error

> {"error":{"message":"(#3503) \"\u003Ctitle xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">xxxxx is an invalid value for property \"article\" with type \"Reference\"","type":"OAuthException","code":3503}}

Please advice how should I set a "reference" property type